# jenkins workflow "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm currently trying to construct my Maven Job with Jenkins Workflow plugin.
In maven job it's possible to set Build Trigger options to **"Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"**.
Is there any way to translate this option to Workflow job? I really don't want to transcribe those dependencies manually (there are a lot of them).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Build pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) plugin and create a view giving your top module as the initial job[image]. It will automatically setup all the jobs according to it's dependencies.