# Jenkins pipeline Incremental build(maven)

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anybody know how to get feature "Incremental build - only build changed modules" from [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) available from inside jenkins declarative pipeline (Jenkinsfile)

Comment: You can setup the build to only build incrementally in Maven using the incremental-build-plugin. See this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624122/jenkins-building-a-product-consisting-of-many-maven-projects-with-jenkins-pipe

Comment: @JonathanCavell  -- I've tried to use this plugin, but seems it's out of date or something, maven can't really download it - [Dependency Repository Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.maven-incremental-build/incremental-build-plugin)